# Como Autollenar las cajas de texto, desde su numero de identificacion "DNI" en PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, autocompletar

como puedo autocompletar los campos Nombre y Apellido, una vez que se halla escrito el numero de documento relacionado al usuario, la idea es que se valide si existe este Nro de documento en la base de datos, luego autocompletar automaticamente y luego poder insertar el E-mail el cual es el objetivo, para poder agregarlo a la informacion del usuario.

el DNI es = al Nro de documento.

Adjunto imagen y codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php 

include("con_db.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['dni']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['apellido']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1) {
        $dni = trim($_POST['dni']);
        $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellido = trim($_POST['apellido']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $fecha = date("d/m/y");
        //$consulta = "INSERT INTO registro(dni, nombre, apellido, email, fecha) VALUES ('$dni','$nombre','$apellido','$email','$fecha')";
        
        $consulta = "UPDATE registro SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido', email='$email' WHERE dni='$dni'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="ok">¡Actualisaste tus Datos Corecctamente!</h3>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
           <?php
        }
        }else {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="bad">¡Por favor complete los campos!</h3>
           <?php
            }
    
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código en forma de texto por favor? Puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta (el botón editar se encuentra abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas) 
y pegando el código en la pregunta. Para darle formato, puedes seleccionar todo el código y presionar las {} que están arriba de la caja de texto.
En este link se explica la importancia de NO poner capturas de código en una pregunta: 
[Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu)

Comment: Gracias por la corrección estimado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar para lo que quieres ajax. En el momento en que cambies de input, puedes hacer una llamada a una función de ajax que recoja el valor del dni introducido en el primer input, esto hará una llamada a una función php que ejecutará una consulta a la db con ese dni, el cual, si todo está bien relacionado en la db, debería de extraer los datos el usuario.

Posteriormente, si la respuesta ha sido satisfactoria, podrías con jquery extraer los datos de tu respuesta y setearlos en los inputs correspondientes.

Sería algo como esto:

```
$.ajax(
   url: "tu ruta o archivo.php", 
   Method:"post o get" en este caso sería una petición get, 
   Data: {"dni" : $("#idInput o clase").val(), 
   success: function(response) {
      Setea response.valor dentro de tu input
   }, 
   Error: function(response) {
     Captura el error y haz algo con el, por ejemplo un alert
   } 
);
```

Php:

Crear función que ejecute una query y reciba el DNI del ajax

Más o. Menos este sería el pseudocodigo que deberías hacer. Siento no ser de más ayuda, estoy desde el móvil y por eso no puedo hacer mucho más xD. Espero te haya guiado.

Suerte y un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la guia estimado, habra un tutorial para este caso? o alguna palabra clave para poder buscar la solucion?

Comment: @Ricardo Perez Zurita sólo tienes que buscar en Google ajax jquery tendrás cientos de guías.